# Permission Set Assignment using apex

Tags: apex, permission-sets

Is there a limitation with PermsissionSetAssignment object in Apex. can't we insert the records using apex?

I am unable to compile the class as it is saying "Variable does not exist: AssigneeId" and "Variable does not exist: PermissionSetId"

```
public static void insertperms(){
        PermissionSetAssignment ps = new PermissionSetAssignment();
                ps.AssigneeId = UserInfo.getUserId();
                ps.PermissionSetId = 'qweqweqwe'; 
               // permList.add(ps);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What API Version are you using? *This object is available in API version 22.0 and later.*

Comment: API version is 42.0

Comment: Did someone define a custom class named `PermissionSetAssignment` in your org?

Comment: I can confirm that this should work, I used this code myself just today: `insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = testUser.Id, PermissionSetId = testPermSet.Id);`

Comment: @Mark Pond, rightly said, there was same class name. All set for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a probable naming collision. If someone created a class named `PermissionSetAssignment` in your org, you would get exactly this error. To work around it, you can use the more verbose `Schema.SomeStandardOjbect` notation.

```
Schema.PermissionSetAssignment assignment = new Schema.PermissionSetAssignment();
```

It's not a great idea to introduce this type of naming collision. If it's not too late to change course, I suggest doing so.

Comment: Based on the provided screenshot and the error list, yeah there's a class named `permissionSetAssignment` that is at least 52 lines long. :-)

Comment: @MarkPond Haha good point. Started typing this answer out before that got added.

Comment: Which one should I mark answer? both of you gave the answers :)

Comment: There's only one `Answer` here and several `Comments`.